Build only one package with rpm-build, and do not install additional build dependencies
I'm trying to build a rpm package partially. Take subversion for example, it would build these packages by default:
subversion-1.7.14-16.el7.x86_64.rpm
subversion-devel-1.7.14-16.el7.x86_64.rpm
subversion-gnome-1.7.14-16.el7.x86_64.rpm
subversion-javahl-1.7.14-16.el7.x86_64.rpm
subversion-kde-1.7.14-16.el7.x86_64.rpm
subversion-libs-1.7.14-16.el7.x86_64.rpm
subversion-perl-1.7.14-16.el7.x86_64.rpm
subversion-python-1.7.14-16.el7.x86_64.rpm
subversion-ruby-1.7.14-16.el7.x86_64.rpm
subversion-tools-1.7.14-16.el7.x86_64.rpm

It would require a lot of build dependencies like KDE or Xorg. My question is how can I build only the first cli rpm without the rest.
Any ideas?
The mentioned source package is here: http://vault.centos.org/7.9.2009/os/Source/SPackages/subversion-1.7.14-16.el7.src.rpm

In general: You can't; that's not how building RPM packages works: These are just the files from the same build process, divided up into different packages. So, you still need to do the full build.
For some packages, there's bcond in the spec files that you can change or that depend on your building platform. If you read the current fedora subversion.spec, you'll see that if you're using RHEL 7 (which is <9, line 21), all your ruby python2, pyswig, bdb… are disabled anyways. (the current fedora rawhide version of subversion.spec doesn't build on ancient RHEL7, however, because RPM
macros are missing; so, since you seem to have a RHEL 7-compatible spec somewhere, you probably want to transfer that whole directory to your build machine and do the mockbuild I describe below there.)
You're building for an old platform, which means you probably should have a fedora development machine, in which you use fedpkg mockbuild --root /etc/mock/centos-7-x86_64.cfg for the spec with your reduced feature set.
